# #1064 error in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error when I execute the query below and I could not figure out the problem. Can anyone please help?

```
SELECT shifts.consultant_uid AS consultant_uid, shifts.status AS 
status , shifts.pay_roll_no AS pay_roll_no, shifts.week_ending AS week_ending, shifts.shifts_date AS shifts_date, shifts.description AS description, shifts.units AS units, shifts.pay_rate AS pay_rate, shifts.charge_rate AS charge_rate, shifts.pay_amount AS pay_amount, shifts.charge_amount AS charge_amount, shifts.margin_amount AS margin_amount, shifts.client_name AS client_name, consultant.user_name AS consultant_name, 

FROM a_shifts AS shifts

LEFT JOIN a_users AS consultant ON shifts.consultant_uid = consultant.user_uid
WHERE 1 

AND week_ending >=  '2013-03-17'
AND week_ending <=  '2013-03-24'
```

Comment: You should reduce your query to a version which includes *only enough to be valid and still break*.

Comment: you should provide error description you are getting while executing this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end of your field list in the `SELECT` clause:

```
... consultant.user_name AS consultant_name,
```

As a general word of advice, usually the actual error indicates where in the query the error was encountered.  In most cases, the location it indicates is *just after* the problem, because it's the first thing the query encountered which it was unable to parse (in this case, the `FROM` keyword) that generates the error.

Comment: @FenixDolores you can set answer as right to set your question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove , before FROM clause

```
SELECT .........consultant.user_name AS consultant_name,
FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT shifts.consultant_uid AS consultant_uid, shifts.status AS 
status , shifts.pay_roll_no AS pay_roll_no, shifts.week_ending AS week_ending, shifts.shifts_date AS shifts_date, shifts.description AS description, shifts.units AS units, shifts.pay_rate AS pay_rate, shifts.charge_rate AS charge_rate, shifts.pay_amount AS pay_amount, shifts.charge_amount AS charge_amount, shifts.margin_amount AS margin_amount, shifts.client_name AS client_name, consultant.user_name AS consultant_name

FROM a_shifts AS shifts

LEFT JOIN a_users AS consultant ON shifts.consultant_uid = consultant.user_uid
WHERE 1 

AND week_ending >=  '2013-03-17'
AND week_ending <=  '2013-03-24'
```